# Output last letter of a string

Tags: java, string

Can some one please help i am in a beginner programming course and i can not get my program to output the last letter of a string?  Here is my program:

```
public class String {   
    private static java.lang.String string;     

    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {      
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);                             
        System.out.println("Enter a string: "); //user enters a word                      
        java.lang.String word = input.nextLine();               
        System.out.print("The length of " + word + " is " +          
        word.length()); //gives the number of characters in the word         
        java.lang.String length = input.nextLine();                 
        System.out.print("The first character: " + word.charAt(0)); //gives the first letter of word        
        java.lang.String first = input.next();              
        System.out.print("The last character: " + word.charAt(4)); //gives the last letter of word      
        java.lang.String last = input.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course because you are getting the char at index 4, not the last one. To get the last index, string.length - 1

Answer (score 1):

You know how to get the length of the word, you did it here:

```
System.out.print("The length of " + word + " is " + word.length());
```

But when you try to get the last letter, instead of using that information, you use the constant "4" :

```
System.out.print("The last character: " + word.charAt(4)); //gives the last letter of word
```

Try to combine your two answers. But also note the comment on your post about subtracting one from the length.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("last character: " +
                       string.substring(string.length() - 1));
```

Hope it helps!